# How can I view the CPU fan speed on a Dell OptiPlex 3070?

Tags: dell, fan

I have a Dell OptiPlex 3070 running Ubuntu Server. It is the smaller form factor version of this computer. I would like to know how I can read out the current fan speed of the single fan that is in the system (I assume this would be the CPU fan). Here is the output of `sensors` and there is no fan speed listed.

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +33.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 0:        +31.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 1:        +30.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 2:        +33.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 3:        +32.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +36.0°C

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +29.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +29.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +30.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

Here is the Ubuntu version I'm running:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Output of `sensors-detect`

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3070
# Board: Dell Inc. 02N3WF
# Kernel: 5.15.0-67-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100T CPU @ 3.10GHz (6/158/11)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): YES
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): YES
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0xcab0
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): YES
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): YES
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): YES
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.4: Cannon Lake-H (PCH)

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at efa0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES
Client found at address 0x50
Handled by driver `ee1004' (already loaded), chip type `ee1004'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus misc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: AUX C/DDI C/PHY C (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: AUX D/DDI D/PHY D (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

I found this and tried it out `sudo modprobe i8k force=1`. After running that command the output of `sensors` is this:

```
$ sensors
dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        1184 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 0:        +55.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 1:        +52.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 2:        +52.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)
Core 3:        +61.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +82.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +53.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

Comment: post the output of `sensors-detect`

Comment: Hello, `sensors-detect` is some sort of interactive shell with a bunch of questions I need to answer. When I first run that I see this:

Sorry the three backticks don't work in comments I cannot properly format this. This is a terrible system, I can't properly reply to your question I'm sorry. Can't even do line breaks. This is useless.

# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3070
# Board: Dell Inc. 02N3WF
# Kernel: 5.15.0-67-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100T CPU @ 3.10GHz (6/158/11)

Is that what you want? Or do you want me to post more?

Comment: edit the question with the output, it won't work in the comments.  Answer Yes to most of the questions in `sensors-detect`.  Pay attention to the Super I/O section.

Comment: Thank, I've edited the question with the full output of `sensors-detect`

Comment: `Found unknown chip with ID 0xcab0` unfortunately means the system can't detect what driver to use for this Super I/O chip which is what will give you fan speed information.  Sometimes there is a workaround but I can't find one for this chip ID.

Comment: I did manage to find something myself and I just tried it. I executed this command ` sudo modprobe i8k force=1` and when I type sensors I see a RPM value. Dunno if it is accurate but there's only one fan. I've put the output of sensors in the question since it's not possible to do it in a comment. But after a reboot it's gone. So I have to figure out how to persist that change after a reboot.

Comment: add it to `/etc/modules` without the modprobe part.

Answer (score 0):

Low level approach without installing anything:

```
cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_input
```

Try to go through neighboring directories...